# See version history of a view definition in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ddl

Within BigQuery, is there a way to see previous versions of the DDL definition of a view? I want to understand when a view was changed and what the changes were. Basically like a Git diff.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sink as per documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#creating_sink) to BigQuery and use below query to identify the changes to the views

```
SELECT  
  resource.labels.dataset_id,
  resource.labels.project_id,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.methodName,r'.*\.([^/$]*)') as method,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.resourceName,r'.*tables\/([^/$]*)') as tableName,
  protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail,
  protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson,
    receiveTimestamp
FROM `playground.sandbox_dataset.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_activity` 
WHERE 
-- enter your date from which you want to find the changed views ---
DATE(timestamp) >= "2023-05-24" and 
-- enter your views you want to know undergone change ---
REGEXP_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.resourceName,r'.*tables\/([^/$]*)') like '%firstView%' 
and protopayload_auditlog.methodName = 'google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob'
```

alter native to this is you can go to Cloud logging dashboard and use query to -protoPayload.methodName="google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob" but this means you will visually have to inspect the changes! which may not good solution.